# How much amount/quantity of food to be eat per day for spiritual person?

Tags: food, spirituality

How much amount/quantity  of food  to be eat   per day  for spiritual person?

I have  read  the  books  of swami sivananda  He  said that to become  an Spiritual person, food play great role  in spiritual  development.

My confusion is that how much amount/quantity  of food  to be eat   per day  for spiritual person?

Comment: More than quantity I think it is the quality of food you eat. Whether it is Sattvika, Rajasika or Tamasika. A spiritual person like a saint should ideally eat Sattvika food.

Comment: 'Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God.'-Jesus. The desire for animal food goes when these things are seen in a man. And where such indications are absent, and yet you find men siding with the non-­killing party, know it for a certainty that here there is either hypocrisy or a show of religion - Swami Vivekananda, Spirituality has to do with spirit realization which is the source of understanding of right and wrong. Only orthodox of Kaliyuga will whine for not eating beef or pork.

Comment: Its sheer stupidity to make non-Indian regions vegetarian without fertile lands growing ample wheat,rice for spiritual purpose.Food play a role for an advanced spiritual persons like Sanyassis, for normal person first step is detachment from senses and ego via Gyana or Bhakti Yoga.https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40332/20656 Only a balanced diet is needed which any sane person can understand. Spirituality is 'chop wood carry water', only the perspective towards life has to be changed not food,robes, occupation which is mere hypocrisy of body & has nothing to do with spirit or spirituality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is

> How much amount/quantity of food to be eat per day for spiritual person?

---

Sri Krishna says in BG, as follows:

> नात्यश्नतस्तु योगोऽस्ति न चैकान्तमनश्नतः।
>
> न चातिस्वप्नशीलस्य जाग्रतो नैव चार्जुन।।6.16।।
>
> But, O Arjuna, ***Yoga is not for one who eats too much, nor for one who
>   does not eat at all;*** neither for one who habitually sleeps too long,
>   nor surely for one who keeps awake.

So spiritually inclined person should partake moderate food.

> युक्ताहारविहारस्य युक्तचेष्टस्य कर्मसु।
>
> युक्तस्वप्नावबोधस्य योगो भवति दुःखहा।।6.17।।
>
> Yoga becomes a destroyer of sorrow of **one whose eating and movements
>   are regulated**, whose effort in works is moderate, and whose sleep and
>   wakefulness are temperate.